# Ember CLI - RESTAdapter for 3rd party API

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, tumblr, ember-cli

I can get data into my app with ic.ajax, but it seems like I should be using the RESTAdapter. The explanations are so simplified, that I'm not sure what to do in various cases. This is what I *think* should work:  (and does with fixtures, a local express server, and http-mocks)

I'm going to use tumblr as the example - since it's always been friendly API in general.

#### router.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import config from './config/environment';

var Router = Ember.Router.extend({
  location: config.locationType
});

Router.map(function() {

  // tumblr posts
  this.resource('posts', {
    path: '/tumblr'
  });

});

export default Router;
```

#### routes/post.js

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('post');
  }

});
```

So, as far as I can tell - `find()` is some *magic* ajax call... but what if I want to specify jsonp or something?

#### adapters/post.js

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

var tumblrBlogName = 'feministlibraryonwheels'; // friends site
var tumblrApiKey = 'UbB4p0GxqNa6wUa8VwpIdqtywjIiA6vljZXyI9wkx9hnQnAFyk';
var tumblrRequestUrl = 'http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/' + tumblrBlogName + '.tumblr.com' + '/posts?api_key=' + tumblrApiKey;

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({

  host: tumblrRequestUrl

});
```

This is a little whacky, because the long tumblr endpoint-thing is so squirly - I feel like it should just be `http://api.tumblr.com` and maybe there is another way to specify the other stuff... or does it just *somehow know*... very confused... seems like namespace: 'v2' is what that option would be for...

#### templates/posts.hbs

```
<section class='container stage'>
<div class='inner-w'>

    <h2>tumblr posts</h2>

    <ul class='block-list event-list'>
        {{#each}}
            <li>
                {{title}}
            </li>

        {{else}}
            No posts are coming up... what's up with that?
        {{/each}}
    </ul>

</div>
</section>
```

Then this `{{#each}}` just knows what it's supposed to look for in most cases - but I would like to be explicit.

---

In all the tutorials I've seen, it's a local server - or http-mocks - and it's just something like this:

```
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({

  host: 'localhoststuff:3000',
  namespace: 'api'

});
```

Then on top of this - I get what seems like a cors issue `GET http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/feministlibraryonwheels.tumblr.com/posts?api_key=UbB4p0GxqNa6wUa8VwpIdqtywjIiA6vljZXyI9wkx9hnQnAFyk/posts 401 (Not Authorized)`

and it's not like it's really hidden... [http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/feministlibraryonwheels.tumblr.com/posts?api_key=UbB4p0GxqNa6wUa8VwpIdqtywjIiA6vljZXyI9wkx9hnQnAFyk][1]

### What is the missing link between many quick tutorials - and the RESTAdapter in the real world - with real API's ??? Any direction will be very appreciated.

Also, here is some `ic.ajax()` attempts I was making as well. The payload gets to the console - but it gets foggy when trying to get the data into the templates

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import ajax from 'ic-ajax';

export default Ember.Route.extend({

  model: function() {
    var libraryData = ajax({
      url: 'http://www.librarything.com/api_getdata.php?userid=F.L.O.W.&showstructure=1&showTags=1&booksort=title_REV',
      type: 'get',
      dataType: 'jsonp'
    });
    console.log(libraryData);
    return libraryData;
  }

});
```

---

EDIT: the 2.4 docs are pretty great. Ember data is stable. You need to know what type of JSON you're getting an if it isn't JSON API format then you need to serialize the data and mold it into that format.

Answer (score 3):

### UPDATE for [Ember 1.13.0](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/18/ember-data-1-13-released.html), [Ember Data 1.13.0](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/18/ember-data-1-13-released.html) and above

**Tools (Adapters and Serializers)**

To connect to an API that isn't Ember-Data friendly (like tumblr) you have to [customize an adapter](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/models/customizing-adapters/) such as the [RESTAdapter](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html) or [JSONAPIAdapter](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPIAdapter.html) to build the request properly.

*(The  JSONAPIAdapter is a subclass of RESTAdapter that adjusts a few things for a JSON API such as the `Accept: application/vnd.api+json` header required by the specs)*

Further, if the data retrieved doesn't follow the [<strike>Ember Data JSON</strike>](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_json-conventions) [JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/) format, you should [customize a serializer](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/models/customizing-serializers/) such as the [JSONSerializer](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONSerializer.html), [RESTSerializer](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html) or [JSONAPISerializer](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPISerializer.html) to format and massage the data by selecting the most appropriate serializer to the data returned by your backend. Here's a short summary of these 3 serializers:

**JSONSerializer**:

- Base serializer (extends the abstract DS.Serializer)
- Provides normalization hooks to massage the data received
- Provides serialization hooks to massage the data sent
- Expects the usual JSON format

  ```
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Bob",
    "friends": [array of friend ids],
    "links": {
      "home": "/bobshome"
    }
  }
  ```

**RESTSerializer**:

- Extends JSONSerializer
- Expects a similar JSON format (with a "root"):

  ```
  {
    "user": {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Bob",
      "friends": [array of friend ids],
      "links": {
        "home": "/bobshome"
      }
    }
  }
  ```

**JSONAPISerializer**

- Extends JSONSerializer
- Expects a [compliant JSON API](http://jsonapi.org/) payload.

In general, we can **mix and match adapters and serializers** to whatever fits best our data and URL endpoint structure. Each of these can be applied on a per-application or per-model basis.

---

**Methods**

When building the request, depending on the exact behavior you need, you should override [appropriate hooks](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/06/18/ember-data-1-13-released.html#toc_reorganized-find-methods) provided by the Ember Data Store (in the Adapter):

[image: Ember Data Find Methods]

Each of the hooks above has an appropriate `normalize{{HOOK_NAME}}Response` method in the serializer (for example `normalizeFindRecordResponse`) where data can be massaged depending on the way we request it (which hook we call):

---

**Examples**

Let's say we want to get Bob's Tumblr blog called "mynameisbob".

Here's a **generic** example how to do that:

```
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    namespace: 'v2/blog/',           // https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/models/customizing-adapters/#toc_endpoint-path-customization
    host: 'https://api.tumblr.com',  // https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/models/customizing-adapters/#toc_host-customization
    headers: {                       // https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.0.0/models/customizing-adapters/#toc_headers-customization
        'api_key': 'abcdefg'
    }

    // set any default ajax options you might need
    ajaxOptions(url, type, options = {}) {
        options.crossDomain = true;                   // make it CORS
        options.dataType = 'jsonp';
        return this._super(url, type, options);
    }

    // find a blog
    findRecord: function(store, type, id, snapshot) {
        const URL = this.buildURL(type.modelName, id, snapshot, 'findRecord');
        return this.ajax(URL, 'GET');
    }
});
```

Usage in a `Route`:

```
// ...
model() {
    return this.store.findRecord('blog', 'mynameisbob');
}
// ...
```

However, there are multiple ways to achieve this. You can also store the api key  and the host url as properties of your adapter and just use them to build the URL (using the [buildURL](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.JSONAPIAdapter.html#method_buildURL) hook):

```
export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    hostUrl: 'https://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog'
    apiKey: 'abcdefg',

    buildURL: function(modelName, id, snapshot, requestType, query) {
        // customize the url based on the parameters
        // lets assume the id is the blog name
        return `${this.get('hostUrl')}/${id}.tumblr.com/posts?api_key=${this.get('apiKey')}`;
    }

    // find a blog
    findRecord: function(store, type, id, snapshot) {
        const URL = this.buildURL(type.modelName, id, snapshot, 'findRecord');
        return this.ajax(URL, 'GET');
    }
});
```

[Here's a Github Repo](https://github.com/nem035/ember-custom-api-example) for a simple Ember app communicating with the Github API

Community driven Adapters to serve as examples:

- [emberobserver.com](http://emberobserver.com/categories/data)
- [github.com](https://github.com/search?q=ember%20data%20adapter&ref=cmdform)
- [bower.io](http://bower.io/search/?q=ember-data-)

Some useful readings:

- [Fit Any Backend Into Ember](http://emberigniter.com/fit-any-backend-into-ember-custom-adapters-serializers/)
- [Adapter Patterns in Ember](http://brewhouse.io/blog/2015/03/06/adapter-patterns-in-ember-js.html)

---

#### Pre Ember 1.13.0

Here is a simple example on how to write a custom [RestAdapter](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html). Essentially, what you need to do is to overwrite the store lookup hooks you need (`find`, `findAll`, `findQuery` ...), as well as `buildURL()`.

Since it's an external API and we need to worry about CORS, we should also override the `ajax` hook.

Custom Tumblr Adapter:

```
App.TumblrAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({

    buildURL: function(type, id, record) {
        var tumblrBlogName = 'feministlibraryonwheels';
        var tumblrApiKey = 'abcdefg';
        var tumblrRequestUrl = 'http://api.tumblr.com/v2/blog/' + tumblrBlogName + '.tumblr.com' + '/posts?api_key=' + tumblrApiKey;
        return tumblrRequestUrl;
    },

    ajax: function(url, method, hash) {
        hash = hash || {};                         // hash may be undefined
        hash.crossDomain = true;                   // make it CORS
        hash.xhrFields = {withCredentials: true};
        return this._super(url, method, hash);
    },

    find: function(store, type, id, record) {
       // customization here or within buildURL
       return this.ajax(this.buildURL(), 'GET');
    },

    findAll: function(store, type, sinceToken) {
        // customization here or within buildURL
        return this.ajax(this.buildURL(), 'GET');
    },

    findQuery: function(store, type, query) {
        // customization here or within buildURL
        return this.ajax(this.buildURL(), 'GET');
    },

    findMany: function(store, type, ids, owner) {
        // customization here or within buildURL
        return this.ajax(this.buildURL(), 'GET');
    }
});
```

If the response isn't properly formatted for Ember Data, we can fix it quickly in the `ajax` hook with a simple promise:

```
ajax: function(url, method, hash) {
    hash = hash || {};                         // hash may be undefined
    hash.crossDomain = true;                   // make it CORS
    hash.xhrFields = {withCredentials: true};
    return this._super(url, method, hash).then(function(json) {
        // Massage data to look like RESTAdapter expects.
        return { tumblrs: [json] };
    });
},
```

If you wish to properly define all the Models with relationship, you will need to implement a custom [RESTSerializer](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html) to massage the data properly.

Here is a [simple jsbin example](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/osULomo/3/edit?html,js,output) I came across on while researching these things myself.

Comment: Trying to make sense of this. Thanks for the help.

Comment: I know you used the word simple 3 times, but I guess that is subjective. LOL.

Comment: @sheriffderek haha i know, it took me while to get a hang of this stuff as well, let me know if you need me to clarify something, but you do need to read the Ember documentation thoroughly, especially the API pages for RESTAdapther and RESTSerializer where all these methods are explained

Answer (score 3):

Using Ember 1.13.3.

With regard to Tumblr specifically, I have the following in adapters/post.js. Hopefully this helps you.

```
import DS from "ember-data";

export default DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'https://api.tumblr.com',
    namespace: 'v2/blog/example.tumblr.com',
    apiKey: 'example',

    ajaxOptions() {
        var hash = this._super.apply(this, arguments);
        hash.data = hash.data || {};
        hash.data.api_key = this.get('apiKey');
        hash.dataType = 'jsonp';
        return hash;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

tumblr, while seeming to be a friendly api, isn't really so friendly with Ember. Ember Data expects a very specific json format, and if the response doesn't match it won't seem so 'magical' or 'just work' like so many of the simplified tutorials out there.

find function: [not so magic](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/master/packages/ember-data/lib/adapters/rest_adapter.js#L343-L345)

You are on the right track (defining a custom adapter). You might look into overriding buildURL inside your adapter.

Have a read [here](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTAdapter.html) and [here](http://emberjs.com/api/data/classes/DS.RESTSerializer.html#property_normalizeHash) for more details about how to munge the incoming json into a form Ember likes.

If you put up a jsbin I can take a look at it.

Comment: Part of CLI is the file convention. In jsbin, can you have a full CLI environment?

Comment: No, but if you post it ther with mockjax it might be easier for someone to help you at which point u yourself can conve ert it back to CLI